# Conways Game of life - All Cells dead in the visualiser

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

For a school project I have to complete a Conways game of life with recourse to some provided skeleton code.

My problem is that all of my cells seem to initialise as dead (and thus do not come alive) when I use the visualiser - I'm not looking for direct answer on the whole project, just some direction on where my code is broken (Apologise for the awful formatting, its my first time on here):

Below is the `Cell.class` and below that is the `CellGrid` - the visualiser was provided.

```
package simulation;

/**
 * This class represents a single Cell in the grid.
 * 
* Complete this class as part of the core of the assessment.
* You must implement the constructor, isAlive, setAlive and isAliveNextStep.
*/

public class Cell
{
// true if the cell is alive and false if it is dead
private boolean alive;

/**
 * Cell constructor - all cells should start out dead
 */
public Cell() 
{
    alive = false;
}

/**
 * Accessor method for alive
 * 
 * @return true if the cell is currently alive; false otherwise
 */
public boolean isAlive() 
{
    if (alive == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}

/**
 * Mutator method for alive
 * 
 * @param alive - the new state of the cell
 */
public void setAlive(boolean alive)
{
    if (alive == true)
        alive = false;
    else alive = true;
}


/**
 * Determine whether this cell should be alive in the next step, 
 * given the number of surrounding neighbours.
 * 
 * See the assignment specification sheet to determine the rules 
 * for living and dead cells.
 * 
 * @param numNeighbours - the number of living cells surrounding this cell
 * @return true if the cell should be alive; false otherwise
 */
public boolean isAliveNextStep(int numNeighbours) 
{
    if (numNeighbours <= 2)
        return false;
    if (numNeighbours == 3)
        return true;
    if (numNeighbours == 4 && alive == true)
        return true;
    if (numNeighbours == 5)
        return false;
    if (numNeighbours > 5)
        return true;
    else return false;

}
}
```

CellGrid class:

```
package simulation;

/**
* This class represents an n x n grid of Cells.
 * 
* Complete this class as part of the core of the assessment.
* You must implement the constructor, simulateStep, isValidCoordinate, 
* countNeighbours, getCell and setCell.
*/
public class CellGrid
{
// Store the cells of the game in this 2D array
private Cell[][] cells;

/**
 * Constructor for a CellGrid. Populates the grid with cells that will be
 * either living or dead. Consider using Math.random() in order to generate 
 * random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0, in conjunction with lifeChance.
 * 
 * @param size - the size of the grid will be size x size
 * @param lifeChance - the probability of each cell starting out 
 * alive (0.0 = 0%, 1.0 = 100%)
 */
public CellGrid(int size, double lifeChance)
{
    cells = new Cell[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cells[i][j] = new Cell();
        if (Math.random() < lifeChance);
        {
            cells[i][j].setAlive(false);
        }
    }

    }
}

/**
 * Run one step in the simulation. This has 2 stages in the following order:
 * 
 * 1. (Core) Update all cells in the grid according to the rules given in the
 * assignment specification sheet.
 * 
 * 2. (Extension) Evolve the cells by calculating their new genes - also 
 * see the assignment specification sheet.
 */
public void simulateStep()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < cells.length; j++)
    {

        int Neighbours = countNeighbours(i, j);

        cells[i][j].isAliveNextStep(Neighbours); 
    }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the given coordinates are inside the grid of cells.
 * 
 * @param x - the x coordinate (column) of the cell
 * @param y - the y coordinate (row) of the cell
 * @return true if the given coordinates are inside the grid of cells; false
 *         otherwise.
 */
public boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y)
{
    int validc = 0; //*variable to check for validity of coordinate by traversal *//

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j > cells.length; j++)
    {
        if (x == i+1 && y == j+1)
        {
            validc = 1;
        }
    }

    }
    if (validc == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
        else return false;
}

/**
 * Count the number of living neighbours in the 8 cells surrounding the
 * given coordinates.
 * 
 * @param x - the x coordinate (column) of the cell
 * @param y - the y coordinate (row) of the cell
 * @return the number of living neighbours of the cell at the given
 *         coordinates; or 0 if the coordinates are invalid.
 */
public int countNeighbours(int x, int y) 
{
    int N = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j > cells.length; j++)
    {

        if (i-1 >= 0 && j-1 >= 0 && cells[i-1][j-1].equals(true))
            N++; 
        if (i-1 >= 0 && cells[i-1][j].equals(true))
            N++; 
        if (i-1 >= 0 && j+1 <= cells.length && cells[i-1][j+1].equals(true))
            N++;    
        if (i >= 0 && j-1 >=0 && cells[i][j-1].equals(true))
            N++;
        if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && cells[i][j].equals(true))
            N++;
        if (i >= 0 && j+1 <= cells.length && cells[i][j+1].equals(true))
            N++;
        if (i+1 <= cells.length && j-1 >= 0 && cells[i+1][j-1].equals(true))
            N++;
        if (i+1 <= cells.length && j >= 0 && cells[i+1][j].equals(true))
            N++;
        if (i+1 <= cells.length && j+1 <= cells.length && cells[i+1][j+1].equals(true))
            N++;
    }

    }
    return N;
}

/**
 * Get the cell at the given coordinates.
 * 
 * @param x - the x coordinate (column) of the cell
 * @param y - the y coordinate (row) of the cell
 * @return the cell at the given coordinates; or null if the coordinates are
 *         invalid
 */
public Cell getCell(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < cells.length && y < cells.length)

    return cells[x][y];

    else return null;

}
/**
 * Set the cell at the given coordinates to the cell provided, if the
 * coordinates are valid.
 * 
 * @param x - the x coordinate (column) of the cell
 * @param y - the y coordinate (row) of the cell
 * @param cell - the new cell to put at the coordinates given.
 */
public void setCell(int x, int y, Cell cell)
{
    cells[x][y] = getCell(x,y);
}
}
```

Comment: I think, your problem might be in your `setAlive` method, where you don't change your class property, but the parameter retrieved by the method.
To simplify your method, I'd use `this.alive = !alive`.

Comment: WTF with your `isAlive()` method. It should simply return alive, that's it. But yeah, @AndrewMcCoist has got your problem. Please study getters and setters -- basic Java. You're over-complicating this to death, that's your main problem. Remember to KISS.

Comment: just a little sidenote, but `Cell.isAlive()` can be simplified a lot. Just return `alive` instead of using that `if-else`-clause. The result'll be just the same.

Comment: Tried both !alive and alive for your recommendation - they definitely simplified it. The problem still is that the cells either are all dead (alive) or live (!alive) and dont change from that - so there probably is an issue with the cellgrid class? Thanks for all of your help by the way!

Comment: The real answer to this question: it's time to learn to use a debugger. You need to look at the innards of your program as it's running to see how it's behaving and the state of its field. It's as simple as that. I suggest that you get cracking.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setAlive` method is incorrect.

```
public void setAlive(boolean alive){
    if (alive == true)
        alive = false;
    else alive = true;
}
```

Due to [variable shadowing](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/shadowed-classes-or-variables-in-java.html), you never really change the field `alive`. It should look like this:

```
public void setAlive(boolean alive){
    this.alive = alive;
}
```

Comment: I've tried changing the class with this and this.alive = !alive; and the result is the same. The cells either are all dead for alive and all alive for !alive. They don't change at all. If I have simple issues like that I imagine I have bigger ones in CellGrid